Legal advice for problems with a coworker in healthcare which can risk professional licensing
I'm writing this in behalf of another person, let him be John.
John is a licensed (university degree) healthcare professional working in the UK. He is having problems with a co-worker, and these problems could put their license at risk. Let me explain:
The problematic co-worker is incompetent and leaves the hospital before their contracted hours have finished. This leaves John as solely responsible for his patients plus the patients of the problematic co-worker, which many times receive poor attention to the point of risking their lives.
John has complained to his boss, who does nothing. A few days ago John was surprised by his boss and the problematic co-worker taking him to a meeting with HR. In the meeting, among other things, John explained the problem of his co-worker leaving before finishing his day; the response of the co-worker was that their boss allowed it. The boss' reaction was to literally say nothing and keep taking notes, and HR didn't comment anything either.
At this point, it seems the problematic co-worker and the boss have some sort of deal or special treatment.
My question is: is it worth to seek legal advice? Maybe not even to sue the hospital; just to understand the actual dangers of the situation, or to understand what can John do to protect himself from being made responsible of any shortcomings of his co-worker. What kind of lawyer could help with this?

This website doesn't provide legal advice.

Note that OP isn't asking for legal advice -- just insight on whether talking to a lawyer is worthwhile.

You're jumping to conclusions. Personnel matters are confidential, they cannot talk about anything in front of the reporting worker.

Is John a member of a medical trade union? If so he could discuss this with his union representative, who might be able to help him escalate and/or find out what is happening behind the scenes. The unions also offer legal assistance including initial advice at no charge. Some solicitors also offer free initial consultations in which they listen you and set out your options. (Sometimes people imagine they would have to pay hundreds of pounds for any legal advice and it puts them off seeking it.)

Yes, if John wants to understand his legal risks, rights or remedies, John should talk to a lawyer -- perhaps an employment lawyer or a lawyer who does medical malpractice.

This answer cites nothing and predictably is false.
